# Python runs but won't write to file

Tags: python, io, output

I want to print a variable to the file word_filter_output.txt. The code runs fine and the variable e prints to the console if I want it to but it will not print to the file. No errors come up. The file is just left with 0 bytes.

```
>>>with open("word_filter_output.txt", "w") as f:
>>>    print(e, file = f)
```

Comment: Just use `f.write(e)`.

Comment: @AlexThornton
It still doesn't work when I write it as:
'with open("word_filter_output.txt", "w") as f:
 f.write(e)'

Comment: Well the code works perfectly for me...

Comment: Is that the full code?

Comment: No. I defined e as a string. It prints to console so I know I made the string correctly. It just won't print to the file.

Comment: @Alex I'll just note the direct equivalent would be `f.write(e + '\n')`

Answer (score 3):

It works as given for me (Python 3.3.4);

depending on what else you are doing, you may need to force-flush it, ie

```
with open("word_filter_output.txt", "w") as f:
    print(e, file=f, flush=True)
```

Comment: @Eschker: what else do you do to the file? Is it possible you are writing to a different directory and looking at an old file (check the timestamp)? Maybe you write to the file, close it, and reopen for writing (which clears the original contents)?

Comment: Thanks! I was checking the wrong file because I didn't know where my directory was.

Comment: I'll just note that `flush=` is 3.3+. Prior to that you'll get an invalid keyword so would need replacing with `f.flush()` after the print instead...